# Keeping element size after saved as image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html2canvas

i have problem using `html2canvas` and `canvas2image`. I'm using this code :

```
$('#preview').click(function () {

var scaleBy = 5;
var w = 1000;
var h = 1000;
var div = document.querySelector('#screenshot');
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = w * scaleBy;
canvas.height = h * scaleBy;
canvas.style.width = w + 'px';
canvas.style.height = h + 'px';
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.scale(scaleBy, scaleBy);

html2canvas(div, {
    canvas:canvas,
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        theCanvas = canvas;
        var dataString = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = 'image';
        link.href = dataString;
        link.click();
    }
});
});
```

`#preview` is a button id for saving an image, the problem is when i save the image as .png its get more space on it. like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl1le.jpg . How do i make the size same like the element after save it to image ? Thanks..

Comment: can you start by explaining why you're setting the canvas dimensions to 5000x5000 ?

Comment: I was change it to 2000, but its still not change anything, why'd i use scale is for make the image unblurry @Cauterite

Answer (score 0):

Html2canvas tries to capture the screenshot of element based on the height & width provided for the element being captured.

Also there is an option to set the height & width of the captured image in html2canvas. Can you try setting your new height and width there? Below is example.
Ex:

```
html2canvas(div, { canvas:canvas,
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
    // ur code logic
   }
  },
  { width: newWidth, height: newHeight}
);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have fix this by myself, thanks for respond my question ;)